# How to position a DHTMLX Popup beside a html component without using co-ordinates

Tags: angularjs, popup, dhtmlx

I have a basic service which creates an manages a dhtmlx popup component. Like so:

```
var popupServices = angular.module('popup.services', []);
popupServices.factory('popupService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope)
{
    this.popupObject = null;
    return{
        createPopup: function(){
            if (!this.popupObject) {
                this.popupObject = new dhtmlXPopup();
            }
        },
        showPopup: function(htmlId,text){
            this.popupObject.attachHTML(text);
            this.popupObject.show(htmlId);
        },
        hidePopup : function() {
            this.popupObject.hide();
        }
    };
}]);
```

I want to pass it the id of the button or html component i want to link the popup to, so in the future if the button is moved, the popup moves with it.

This is an angular application and the following solution will not work :

http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxPopup/samples/01_init/07_custom_object.html

This is regards to the code :

```
window.dhx4.absLeft(inp),
window.dhx4.absTop(inp),
inp.offsetWidth,
inp.offsetHeight
```

Any ideas on how to give a html component an id and linking the popup to that id?

Thanks
Anton

Answer (score 0):

You can implement new prototype showNextToId.
There is the code below, that is based on the sample you've mentioned

```
function showPopup(button) {
    if (!myPop) {
        myPop = new dhtmlXPopup();
        myPop.attachHTML("Button is clicked");
    }
    if (myPop.isVisible()) {
        myPop.hide();
    } else {
        myPop.showNextToId(button.id); // show by id
    }
}
function hidePopup() {
    if (myPop) myPop.hide();
}

// you can move to separate file
dhtmlXPopup.prototype.showNextToId = function(id) {
    if (typeof(id) == "string") id = document.getElementById(id);
    var x = window.dhx4.absLeft(id);
    var y = window.dhx4.absTop(id);
    var w = id.offsetWidth;
    var h = id.offsetHeight;
    this.show(x,y,w,h);
};
```

And input:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" onclick="showPopup(this);"  onblur="hidePopup();" value="click">
```